# Why can't I subscribe to HttpHandlerDiagnosticListener in a .NET Framework application

Tags: .net, system.diagnostics

I am using the code below to enable `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`s to create an activity for every outgoing HTTP request. This works well in an ASP.NET Core application that targets .NET Core 3.1 but it does not work in a 'classic' ASP.NET application that targets .NET Framework 4.7.2.

```cs
// Using the Subscribe(IObservable<T>, Action<T>) extension method from the System.Reactive package
DiagnosticListener.AllListeners.Subscribe(listener =>
{
    if (listener.Name == "HttpHandlerDiagnosticListener")
    {
        listener.Subscribe(diagnostic =>
        {
            if (diagnostic.Key == "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestOut.Start")
            {
                // ...
            }
            else if (diagnostic.Key == "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestOut.Stop")
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main difference that I can think of is that the ASP.NET Core application uses the `DiagnosticListener` type that is built-in to .NET Core, whereas the 'classic' ASP.NET application needs a package reference to System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource to use that type.

I tried with different versions of the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource package (4.6.0, 4.7.0, 4.7.1, 5.0.0, and 5.0.1), rebuilding my project after each up/downgrade of the package, but to no avail.

I found a [GitHub issue about a similar problem in Azure Functions (in-process) applications](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7135). They mention downgrading to System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.7.0 as a workaround, but in my tests that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in [the summary of the `HttpHandlerDiagnosticListener` in the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource package](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/System/Diagnostics/HttpHandlerDiagnosticListener.cs#L16):

> A HttpHandlerDiagnosticListener is a DiagnosticListener for .NET 4.6 and above where HttpClient doesn't have a DiagnosticListener built in. This class is not used for .NET Core because HttpClient in .NET Core already emits DiagnosticSource events. This class compensates for that in .NET 4.6 and above. HttpHandlerDiagnosticListener has no public constructor. To use this, the application just needs to call DiagnosticListener.AllListeners and DiagnosticListener.AllListenerObservable.Subscribe(IObserver{DiagnosticListener}), then in the IObserver{DiagnosticListener}.OnNext(DiagnosticListener) method, when it sees the System.Net.Http.Desktop source, subscribe to it. This will trigger the initialization of this DiagnosticListener.

So I changed my code to this and it works:

```cs
if (listener.Name == "System.Net.Http.Desktop")
{
    listener.Subscribe(diagnostic =>
    {
        if (diagnostic.Key == "System.Net.Http.Desktop.HttpRequestOut.Start")
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if (diagnostic.Key == "System.Net.Http.Desktop.HttpRequestOut.Stop")
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing a peculiar issue, where it works in local but not in Prod. We are using containers and Service Fabric for orchestration. Kindly Suggest!